# Can another user on my WPA2 WiFi network see my DNS requests?

Tags: wifi, dns

On a WiFi network with WPA2 security, can another device see the DNS requests that my device makes?

My understanding is that with HTTPS, no-one can see the content or full URLs that I connect to.

However, would another device on the same WiFi network be able to see the hostnames that my device connects to?

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Does that answer you have marked as a duplicate really answer the question "Can another device see the DNS requests... with HTTPS?"  Seems like a case of "This is an elementary question about X, so we'll redirect you to the canonical question for X even though it may not directly answer your question there".  It'd honestly be more helpful to redirect him to the HTTPS page on Wikipedia than to the question linked.

Comment: The answer is "probably". While there are workarounds to hide or encrypt DNS requests like DNSCrypt or DNS-over-HTTPS, if you don't have these set up you won't be protected, and additionally the underlying TLS protocol will reveal what IP address you're connecting to anyways.

Comment: if you want to see this for yourself download and run a program called Wireshark. It will show you all the traffic on your wifi that it can find, you'll be able to see what requests are visable to other people on the network